# Check a route does not exists in Rails 4

Tags: rspec, capybara, ruby-on-rails-4

I deactivated the user registration (Gem Devise) and I want to make a test to be sure the route `/users/sign_up` does not exists.

To do this I created a test in `spec/features/user_spec.rb`

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'capybara/rspec'

feature "Users" do
  scenario "could not register " do
    expect(:get => "/users/sign_up").not_to be_routable
  end
end
```

When I run this test, I have this error :

```
1) Users could not register
   Failure/Error: expect(:get => "/users/sign_up").not_to be_routable
   NoMethodError:
     undefined method `routable?' for {:get=>"/users/sign_up"}:Hash
   # ./spec/features/user_spec.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-4/docs/routing-specs/be-routable-matcher):

> The be_routable matcher is best used with should_not to specify that a
>   given route should not be routable. **It is available in routing specs
>   (in spec/routing) and controller specs (in spec/controllers).**

Inside a Capybara feature you could do:

```
scenario "could not register " do
  visit("/user/sign_up")
  expect(page.status_code).to be(404)
end
```

Comment: I did move my test inside controller and it works. visit("/user/sign_up") throw a No route matches [GET] "/user/sign_up" for info. Thank for your help !

Answer (score 5):

Got similar issue. The solution is:

.1 Create `spec/routing/users_routing_spec.rb`

.2 Inside that file write:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe UsersController do
  describe "routing" do

    it "routes to #index" do
      expect(:get => "/users/sign_up").not_to be_routable
    end
end
```